# d3.js mapping a dataset into a new one with different keys

Tags: javascript, database, d3.js

I have the following dataset:

```
dataset = [
  {
  'date': '2015-11-11T19:15:00.000Z'
  'cpu': 13
  'ram': 128
  'sessions': 1367
  }
  {
  'date': '2015-11-11T19:16:00.000Z'
  'cpu': 70
  'ram': 128
  'sessions': 3567
  }
  {
  'date': '2015-11-11T19:17:00.000Z'
  'cpu': 25
  'ram': 250
  'sessions': 567
  }
  {
  'date': '2015-11-11T19:18:00.000Z'
  'cpu': 20
  'ram': 120
  'sessions': 4567
  }
]
```

..I would like to create a new dataset as follows:

```
newdataset = [
 { 'cpu': [
     {'date': '2015-11-11T19:15:00.000Z', 'value':13},
     {'date': '2015-11-11T19:16:00.000Z', 'value':70}
   ]
 }
 { 'ram': [
     {'date': '2015-11-11T19:15:00.000Z', 'value':128},
     {'date': '2015-11-11T19:16:00.000Z', 'value':128}
   ]
 }
 { 'sessions': [
     {'date': '2015-11-11T19:15:00.000Z', 'value':1367},
     {'date': '2015-11-11T19:16:00.000Z', 'value':3567}
   ]
 }
]
```

Although I have good understanding of d3.js, I never had previous experience with databases. So far I managed to do this:

```
multiplegroups = d3.keys(dataset[0])
    .filter((key) ->
    key != 'date'
  )

multiplegroups2 = dataset.map (o) ->
  o.cpu
```

With the two functions above I can get to

```
Array [ "cpu", "ram", "sessions" ]
```

and

```
Array [ 13, 70, 25, 20 ]
```

The thing left to do is somehow run the second function x3 times for each key and attach these value arrays to the keys in the array produced by the first function.

The reason I am trying to do this is for a small multiples chart. I mean I could manually produce 3 different arrays using the second function and use them seperately, but am certain there is a better/faster way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In D3 you can do it like this:

```js
var dataset = [{
    'date': '2015-11-11T19:15:00.000Z',
    'cpu': 13,
    'ram': 128,
    'sessions': 1367
  }, {
    'date': '2015-11-11T19:16:00.000Z',
    'cpu': 70,
    'ram': 128,
    'sessions': 3567
  }, {
    'date': '2015-11-11T19:17:00.000Z',
    'cpu': 25,
    'ram': 250,
    'sessions': 567
  }, {
    'date': '2015-11-11T19:18:00.000Z',
    'cpu': 20,
    'ram': 120,
    'sessions': 4567
  }],



  multiplegroups = d3.keys(dataset[0])
  .filter(function(key) {
    return key != "date"; //get all not date key
  }).map(function(d) {
    var ob = {};//iterate on non date keys
    ob[d] = dataset.map(function(d1) {
    //iterate on full data to pluck our desired value
      return {
        date: d1.date,
        value: d1[d]
      };
    });
    return ob;
  });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(multiplegroups, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks, I knew I was close enough, but had no idea how to merge the two functions :)

Answer (score 1):

In plain Javascript, you could write this.

```js
var dataset = [{ 'date': '2015-11-11T19:15:00.000Z', 'cpu': 13, 'ram': 128, 'sessions': 1367 }, { 'date': '2015-11-11T19:16:00.000Z', 'cpu': 70, 'ram': 128, 'sessions': 3567 }, { 'date': '2015-11-11T19:17:00.000Z', 'cpu': 25, 'ram': 250, 'sessions': 567 }, { 'date': '2015-11-11T19:18:00.000Z', 'cpu': 20, 'ram': 120, 'sessions': 4567 }],
    newdataset = function (array) {
        var r = [], o = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            Object.keys(a).filter(function (a) {
                return a !== 'date';
            }).forEach(function (k) {
                if (!o[k]) {
                    o[k] = {};
                    o[k][k] = [];
                    r.push(o[k]);
                }
                o[k][k].push({ date: a.date, value: a[k] });
            });
        });
        return r;
    }(dataset);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(newdataset, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I am looking for a d3 solution